# How to store "stream" and "fields" paramters properly

Tags: 2010, javascript, jquery, column, spservices

I'm trying to use the GetItem method to use for copying documents, but I'm not having luck with the field or stream parameters. Below is an example of how I attempted to store each of them. When I check the status, it returns "success" by the way.

```
 mystream = $(xData.responseXML).find("Stream").text();
                      console.log("mystream= " +mystream); //mystream always returns blank in console

$(xData.responseXML).find("FieldInformation").each(function(){
                    myfields+=$(this).get(0).xml;
                    console.log("myfields= " +myfields);  //myfields also returns blank in console
```

xData.responseText returns something like this: [image]  and eventually ends with the binary followed by

```
</Stream></GetItemResponse></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

When I try to run console.log(xData.responseXML); or console.log(xData.responseXML.xml); 
I get this error from the console: [image]

Comment: What does `xData.responseText` or `xData.responseXML` look like?

Comment: How exactly are you calling `$().SPServices()`? What parameters for it are you using?

Comment: I use: 

operation: "GetItem",
Url: myurl,
async: false,
completefunc: function (xData, Status) {  -- and then the info above

Comment: `async:false` looks like the culprit to me. Try it without that parameter.

Comment: Should I have set it to true? I removed it, and stream and fields still return the same empty values I set them to originally. Should I be using responseText instead of responseXML in finding the stream and fieldinformation?

Comment: Hmmm... that's weird. And you're not getting any errors in console? [This might help you out btw](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21997553/copy-word-document-between-document-libraries-in-different-subsites-sharepoint)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13380/discussion-between-kei-and-user3299197)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For some reason, although most people are able to use

```
$(xData.responseXML).find("FieldInformation").each(function()
```

I was having issues with it, so I used "responseText" in place of "responseXML". 
A user in the comments section helped me solve the issue privately.

update: I found that this issue was simply a bug in jquery 1.9.1.. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13388